# Office JS/Web apps: Excel Range Validation

Tags: office-js

Does the latest API support setting cell/range validation in Excel? I can't seem to find documentation that supports this. Thanks in advance.

Here is the corresponding doc for VSTO:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.validation.aspx

Comment: I logged this in user voice 2 years ago: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/5745674-excel-apps-enable-data-validation-support

Comment: Data validation feature is being worked on and coming to beta shortly..

Comment: Thanks Sudhi, for the update.